# Reference request: Structural Ramsey theorem for finite Boolean algebras

Tags: combinatorics, reference-request, boolean-algebra

The so-called [structural Ramsey theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structural_Ramsey_theory) for finite Boolean algebras was proved by Graham and Rothschild in a paper *Ramsey's Theorem for $n$-parameter sets*, or so I am told.  A problem that I'm having reading the paper is that the said theorem is stated and proved in terms of $n$-parameter sets, with which I am not familiar or comfortable (a single $n$-parameter set is determined by seven parameters!).

Is there a proof of the structural Ramsey theorem for finite Boolean algebras written in terms of Boolean algebras?

*Addendum*: the structural Ramsey theorem that I have in mind is that the category of finite Boolean algebras and embeddings have the Ramsey property as defined in the aforementioned Wikipedia article.

Comment: What's the statement of the structural Ramsey theorem for finite Boolean algebras that you have in mind?

Comment: @MishaLavrov Please see my edit.

Comment: I see now. You might be able to get away with using the Nešetřil-Rödl theorem instead. I can't tell if that's right because all the statements of this theorem I found are in category-theoretical language I find hard to parse, instead of the n-parameter sets I'm happy with. But this might be a positive from your point of view.